# Playwright tests fail in Circleci but pass locally

Tags: testing, continuous-integration, playwright, circleci

I'm trying to add a Circleci job that runs my Playwright tests but they all return a timeout error after 30s even though they pass in local and each test is under 3s.

Here's my Circleci config for the test job:

```
- run:
    command: |
      wait-on http://localhost:3000
      wait-on http://localhost:4466
      npx playwright install --with-deps
      npm run test
    working_directory: e2e
- store_test_results:
    path: ./e2e/results.xml
- store_artifacts:
    path: ./e2e/test-results/client-Shoud-be-able-to-create-a-question/trace.zip
```

And here's one of the test:

```
test.only('Shoud be able to create a question', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto('http://localhost:3000')
  console.log('page url: ', page.url())
  await page
    .locator('button', { hasText: 'Nouvelle question' })
    .first()
    .click()
  await page.locator('input').click()
  await page.locator('input').fill(questionsText[randomQuestion])
  await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'add' }).click()
  await page
    .getByText(tags.tagName, { exact: true })
    .first()
    .click()
  await page.locator('button', { hasText: 'Envoyer la question' }).click()
  await expect(page.getByRole('heading', { name: questionsText[randomQuestion] })).toBeVisible()
})
```

The log is returning localhost:3000

Here's the Circleci error:

```
locator.click: Target closed
=========================== logs ===========================
waiting for locator('button').filter({ hasText: 'Nouvelle question' }).first()
============================================================
```

I've tried putting a waitForSelector but it didn't work.

I'm also using the trace and it's only returning some Graphql request that I have in a beforeAll (they're all working in the trace) and nothing after that (I've got a white screen).

Why is it not working in Circleci even though it's working perfectly fine in local ?

Comment: ,Is it visually going on expected URL and opening page correctly during test run from CircleCI?

Comment: @VishalAggarwal I don't have a visual return of what's happening in Circleci so idk

Comment: The reason I asked as it clearly says target closed so it cannot get to the element as page/browser is closed.

Comment: @VishalAggarwal But why does it close the browser in Circleci but not in my local tests ?

Comment: IDK , I think that's what we are trying to figure out - why. Couple of questions: 1) Was it working before with Circle CI? 2) Did you update playwright version before this? 3) Are you able to execute  any other playwright suite from CircleCI successfully? 4) What version of playwright you are currently using? Does it help to upgrade/downgrade playwright version?

Comment: The other Circleci jobs are working fine.  
I'm on version 1.30.0 of Playwright (I had to downgrade bc I'm using the docker image and above this version it's no longer node v16 and my front does not work). Before I was using the latest version without the playwright docker image and it wasn't working (same error).
I don't have another Playwright test suite (I have 9 tests in one file and they all crash at the line right after the goto).

Comment: It seems there is an open issue related to it. https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/13090

Comment: @VishalAggarwal I already saw this issue but there is nothing that seems helpful (they all have the same problem and there is no fix found)

Answer (score 1):

This is not basically a solution but more of an workaround for an [open issue](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/13090):

Increase [setDefaultNavigationTimeout](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-browsercontext#browser-context-set-default-navigation-timeout) to an arbitrarily high number to handle slow connections as its timeout if it finishes early , it won't wait anyways.

```
browserContext.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(timeout);
```

Something like below in config:

```
// playwright.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from '@playwright/test';

    export default defineConfig({
      use: {
        navigationTimeout: 30 * 1000
      },
    });
```

And then global timeout:

```
// playwright.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from '@playwright/test';

export default defineConfig({
  globalTimeout: 60 * 60 * 1000,
});
```

Comment: Thx for taking your time finding a solution. I can't try it right now so I'll see later if it works :)

Comment: The downvote isn't mine I was sleeping and just turned on my computer. I changed both timeout (I put 60 * 60 * 1000 for both timeouts) plus the test timeout but nothing happens and Circleci make it fail after 10 mins without any output in the console.